# Modelling gravitational potential of a galaxy

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, potential-energy, density, numerical-method

I am interested in modelling the gravitational potential of a disc-shaped galaxy with radius $R$, i.e. solving the [2D Poisson equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson's_equation) numerically by [Gauss-Seidel relaxation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method):

$$\nabla^2 \phi = 4\pi G \rho(x,y)$$

With 
$$
\rho(x,y,t=0) = \begin{cases}\rho_0, & x^2+y^2<R^2 \\ 0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

That is, a constant mass distribution inside the galaxy and no mass outside. I want to solve this equation on some sort of grid with side $L>R$ with the boundary condition that the potential on the boundary of the galaxy vanishes.

I am confused how is it possible to solve for the potential outside the radius $R$. I thought that with Neumann boundary conditions, we can only solve for the potential inside of the region, on whose boundary we know the value of the potential. So how is this supposed to work? How do I calculate the potential outside of this galaxy, in the rest of the grid?

Comment: No, actually at first I'm interested in a very simplistic model, the "galaxy" being essentially a disc of uniform density. And my question is, how is it possible to find the potential outside of the boundary on which I have the boundary condition.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Your density is well defined over the whole region, giving you either a Poisson problem or a Laplace problem. The Gauss-Seidel method works for both problems.

Comment: Again, I don't see what the issue is. You have a boundary at $L$, not $R$. You have a density defined everywhere in $L$, leading to either a Poisson or a Laplace problem, both of which can be solved using the GS method.

Comment: @KyleKanos But my boundary value is at the circle $R$, the potential vanishes there, but I have no clue about the behaviour of the potential at $L$.

Comment: Well, if you really are terribly concerned with boundaries, since it is a constant distribution you can probably analytically compute $\phi(r>R)$ and then insert a Dirichlet boundary instead of the Neumann.

Comment: Or just set $L=R$ and use spherical-polar coordinates, instead of Cartesian coordinates.